# Wrong link between Fact and Dim table SSAS

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas

We have a problem with a Fact table in our cube. 
We know it is not the best practice of developing a Dimensional db but we have dimension and fact table combined in 1 table. 
This is because Dimensional data isn't much (5 fields). But moving on to the problem. 
We have added this table to our cube and for testing we added 1 measure(count of rows). . Like the image says we have the grand total for every sub category this isn't correct.

[image: wrong count of rows].

Does anyone have an idea where we have to look for the problem.

Kind regards,
Phoenix

Comment: "but we have dimension and fact table combined in 1 table" - then fix that first.

Comment: That is not really an option for now because we use this everywhere in our dim db.. And it works for all..

Comment: if you can't design it correctly (and lets face it, it's not exactly rocket science) why bother at all?

Comment: Because like you see in the image I not going to create a new dimension for 50 values and 5 columns.. and then we will be creating a more and more relational database..

Comment: you don't appear to know how to design a fact table?

Comment: Yes I do, but do you always follow conventions 100%

Comment: Only when they make good sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50942/discussion-between-phoenix-and-mitch-wheat)

Comment: lets not.............

Comment: Okay.. do you have another idea on fixing the problem?

Comment: @Phoenix it looks like you haven't defined the relationships between your fact table and dimension, take a look at the dimension usage tab when editing the cube (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365387(v=sql.105).aspx for details)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a relationship between your sub category dimension and your fact table.  That has resulted in the full count mapping to all of the sub category attributes, hence the same value repeating

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a relation between cube measure group and your dimension on the second tab (Dimension Usage) in cube (It's 'regular' and key-level on both sides in most cases).
2. If this relation is exist try to recreate it again. Sometimes it happens after several manual changes in 'advanced' mode.
3. Check dimension mapping in fact table. If everything is ok, try to add new dimension with only one level the first time, than add another one etc. I know it sounds like shaman tricks but still...

And always use SQL Server Profiler on both servers (SQL, SSAS) to capture exact query that returns wrong value. Maybe the mistake is somewhere else.